# Is there a way to disable/prevent custom title bar buttons?

Tags: gnome, icons, titlebar

I am running ubuntu 20.04 on desktop.

I have recently been irritated by several occasions where I went to close or minimise a window, and for a few seconds couldn't see or process the where the buttons were. This is because many many app developers choose to add their own buttons for this purpose, which appear in slightly different locations and with different icons and colours to the system ones. Is there a way to force apps to use the system title bar buttons, or at least force the system ones to appear even if the 'custom' ones have to be present. In my opinion they shouldn't be allowed to use custom title bars, it guarantees visual inconsistency, and let's be honest no developer needs special custom icons, but my opinion is neither here nor there. I greatly appreciate any assistance, so thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. There's absolutely nothing requiring an app developer to use the GNOME libraries to build applications, nor anything preventing them from using low-level graphics calls to build their own windows, buttons, title bars, etc.